# PySpark - Convert list of JSON objects to rows

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to convert a list of objects and store their attributes as columns.

```
{
  "heading": 1,
  "columns": [
    {
      "col1": "a",
      "col2": "b",
      "col3": "c"
    },
    {
      "col1": "d",
      "col2": "e",
      "col3": "f"
    }
  ]
}
```

Final Result

```
heading | col1 | col2 | col3
1       | a    | b    | c
1       | d    | e    | f
```

I am currently flattening my data (and excluding the columns column)

```
df = target_table.relationalize('roottable', temp_path)
```

However, for this use case, I will need the columns column. I saw examples where `arrays_zip` and `explode` was used. Would I need to iterate through each object or is there an easier way to extract each object and convert into a row?

Comment: what is the datatype for `columns`? `string` or `array of struct`?

Comment: columns is array of struct (with the attributes being strings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Spark SQL builtin function: [inline](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#inline) or [inline_outer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#inline_outer) is probably easiest way to handle this (use inline_outer when NULL is allowed in `columns`):

From Apache Hive [document](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-inline):

> Explodes an array of structs to multiple rows. Returns a row-set with N columns (N = number of top level elements in the struct), one row per struct from the array. (As of Hive 0.10.)

```
df.selectExpr('heading', 'inline_outer(columns)').show()                                                           
+-------+----+----+----+
|heading|col1|col2|col3|
+-------+----+----+----+
|      1|   a|   b|   c|
|      1|   d|   e|   f|
+-------+----+----+----+
```